# Logging - always include class attributes

Tags: python, logging

Currently my code logs two types of events. Class related and class unrelated stuff.

I hence have two functions that print info. One outside of the class and one inside because I want to automatically log class attributes with every log without the need to specify them for every `print()` line and just pass the text I want to log / print to the function.

```
import datetime

def logging_andy(strng):
    print(datetime.datetime.now(), "---", strng)

class testClass():        
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        
    def logging_andy(self, strng):
        print(datetime.datetime.now(), "--- ID:", self.id, "/ Name:", "'" + self.name + "'", "---", strng)
        
test1 = testClass(123, "Test Class 1")
test1.logging_andy("This is a test log")

test2 = testClass(456, "Test Class 2")
test2.logging_andy("This is a test log")

logging_andy("This is a log unrelated to the testClass")

OUTPUT:
2020-08-06 19:15:03.747040 --- ID: 123 / Name: 'Test Class 1' --- This is a test log
2020-08-06 19:15:03.748040 --- ID: 456 / Name: 'Test Class 2' --- This is a test log
2020-08-06 19:15:03.748040 --- This is a log unrelated to the testClass
```

I think I would benefit from proper logging but since I haven't ever used it I can't seem to figure out how this should be set up inside the class so that with every message I get the class related attributes but sill to be able to log "outside" of the class.

**WHAT I TRIED:**

I found this https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information but had two issues:

- I wasn't able to replicate the two types of logging I have in my example (one logging class attributes and one just class unrelated text)
- And also the provided example doesn't log what the page says it should, at least for me

My output:

```
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - a.b.c - DEBUG    A debug message
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - a.b.c - INFO     An info message with some parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - CRITICAL A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - DEBUG    A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - WARNING  A message at WARNING level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - INFO     A message at INFO level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - WARNING  A message at WARNING level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - CRITICAL A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - INFO     A message at INFO level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - DEBUG    A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - INFO     A message at INFO level with 2 parameters
2020-08-06 19:20:24 - d.e.f - CRITICAL A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
```

Example output provided in the link:

```
2010-09-06 22:38:15,292 a.b.c DEBUG    IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A debug message
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 a.b.c INFO     IP: 192.168.0.1     User: sheila   An info message with some parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f ERROR    IP: 127.0.0.1       User: jim      A message at ERROR level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f DEBUG    IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f ERROR    IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A message at ERROR level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 192.168.0.1     User: jim      A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f CRITICAL IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at CRITICAL level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,300 d.e.f DEBUG    IP: 192.168.0.1     User: jim      A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,301 d.e.f ERROR    IP: 127.0.0.1       User: sheila   A message at ERROR level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,301 d.e.f DEBUG    IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A message at DEBUG level with 2 parameters
2010-09-06 22:38:15,301 d.e.f INFO     IP: 123.231.231.123 User: fred     A message at INFO level with 2 parameters
```

Comment: Have you come across `vars()` function? It can help you convert your object into dict like this {"id": "Andy", "name": "Test" } which in turn can be string formatted and displayed in plain logs.

Comment: But it might not work for nested class properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Python 3** answer, however should also work for Python 2 syntax.

Logging `extras` argument can help you optionally include variables. You can optionally send in objects (for class context). Here's a way.

1. `ContextFilter` to handle object not present.
2. The `Test` class shall use `__repr__` function to *represent* how to interpret your object.

```py
import logging, sys

class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.obj = record.obj if hasattr(record, "obj") else ""
        return True

class Test():
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name

    def __repr__(self):
        return " ".join(("{}: {}".format(k, v) for k, v in vars(self).items()))

    def log(self, msg):
        LOGGER.error(msg, extra={"obj": self})
```

Setup a simple logger like this:

```py
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)
HANDLE = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
HANDLE.setFormatter(logging.Formatter("%(asctime)-15s %(name)-5s %(levelname)-8s %(obj)-25s %(message)s"))

LOGGER.addFilter(ContextFilter())
LOGGER.addHandler(HANDLE)
```

Compare the two types of statements.

```py
t_andy = Test("001", "Andy")
t_mark = Test("002", "Mark")

t_andy.log("Andy can log.")
t_mark.log("Mark is no less.")

common_log("A common message not involving objects.")
```

Time to see the results:

```py
2020-08-07 00:08:49,976 __main__ ERROR    id: 001 name: Andy        Andy can log.
2020-08-07 00:08:51,918 __main__ ERROR    id: 002 name: Mark        Mark is no less.
2020-08-07 00:08:52,401 __main__ ERROR                              A common message not involving objects.
```

---

Comment: that looks nice, but the thing is I don't want to pass the attributes, because in my real use case, there is a lot of them. I would like to be able to do just `LOGGER.error("Message with obj props logged")` and have the obj attributes be logged automatically, just like in my example.

Comment: huh, i guess i can put this `LOGGER.error("Message with obj", extra={"obj": Test("001", "Andy")})` inside the `logging_andy` function I already have, can't i? I will try tomorrow. thanks for now

Comment: @Seminko checkout my edit. Loggers use different levels. I used ERROR for easiness. Use them judiciously. Hope it helps, green check if it does :)

Comment: btw, what are those number at the end for? `%(asctime)-15s` Wasn't able to find an explanation for those.

Comment: Yeah it's like reserving 15chars for that part of log not more not less. So that when you read logs, it'll look like columns, neat stuff.

Comment: I thought that was the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking back, I feel pretty stupid. The only thing needed was updating my logging function inside and outside of the class.

Thanks to @Abhilash for pointing it out.

```
import logging

loglevel = "DEBUG"

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s %(message)s',
#filename=localdir+'/logs/'+cc+'.log',
level=logging.getLevelName(loglevel),
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
logger=logging.getLogger('main')
logger.setLevel(loglevel)


def logging_andy(strng):
    logger.debug(strng)

class testClass():        
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.logger=logging.getLogger('classLogger')
        self.logger.setLevel(loglevel)
        
    def logging_andy(self, strng):
        self.logger.debug(f"--- ID: {self.id} / Name: '{self.name}' --- {strng}")
        
test1 = testClass(123, "Test Class 1")
test1.logging_andy("This is a text log")

test2 = testClass(456, "Test Class 2")
test2.logging_andy("This is a text log")

logging_andy("This is a log unrelated to a class")
```

Comment: Thought of introducing few new things like vars, loghandlers and formatters. Encourage you to try them all. :)